Bulge near bottom of door jamb near to shower
We are seeing a bulge near door jam next to shower. There is no water coming out of the show past the glass door. I also DO NOT see any water leaking on the drywall behind the shower or on the ceiling of floor underneath. What could be the reason for this ? any thoughts ?


This likely could the be result of water on the floor after a shower.

If it is made from MDF/particle board, they do not like moisture.  Water dripping near there from wet feet/body would be enough.

I agree with @spuck : this does look like water on the floor soaking into the wall substance. Spuck, if you make that an answer I'll upvote it.

This could explained simply by water being on the floor after showering.
This could be caused either a little bit at a time over several weeks/months, or even from one shower where enough water was left in contact with the bottom of the door frame.
How long ago was this bathroom finished? I ask because there is a whitish mark on the floor:

which could be overspray from the door frame being recently painted, or it could be the residue of shower water running and puddling there.
It could be that there is a leak inside the wall, but water on the floor is more likely.

Yep, and water can wick along surfaces too.
